# No Actionbar after making splash screen in my app

Tags: android, android-actionbar

@skillson I have changed in Androidmanifest.XML code but after that, i am facing, unfortunately, my app has stopped. why?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Style.xml code is here.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Simply change the style on your MainActivity.

Comment: Can you please share that code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change apptheme from `styles.xml` if you want to change theme of one activity. It will effect all activities.Use another theme or do it in `AndroidManifest.xml` for that activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. ActionBar is removed now.  
But,
On the Splash screen, only my app name (Text) is showing (On the Top where I removed ActionBar). How to remove that?

Comment: @AsifRaza I don't see any problem. Try adding `android:label=""` to activity attributes.(Updated my answer). That might help.

Comment: Text removed. But when I run my app before coming home page it’s showing error “Unfortunately, AppName has Stopped”. Why? What should I do?? Should I share any other code file with you??

Comment: @AsifRaza See if you can find the location of the `Stop` cause. You might be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Manifest.xml** file and the find your activity in your   and add `android.theme=@style/...LightActionBar` choose a theme with action bar..

Answer (score 0):

The first splash screen `Activity` might have something like the following in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities.SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And the `MainActivity` should have the declaration in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file like this.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="Home"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBarNoElevation" />
```

Here's the `ActionBarNoElevation` theme that goes into your `styles.xml` file.

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarNoElevation" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.ActionBar.ZeroElevation</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.ActionBar.ZeroElevation</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is Style.xml in my project     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>                                                             ---------------------------------

Comment: androidmanifest.xml file<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> </application>

Comment: Please check these files are in my project. Please tell me where are errors?

Comment: This is really hard to understand from the comment. Please update your question and post the layouts there with proper formatting to make it readable.

Comment: I dont konw how to comment in format cz i am new here.

Comment: No. You do not need to format the comment. Just update the question. Click the edit button under your question and then add these content in your question.